# Ulogin парсинг: код, получающий информацию о пользователе

Tags: php, html, ulogin

Здравствуйте. Плагин ulogin как бы состоит из двух частей: первая сама "форма" авторизации (к примеру, b23.ru/ywax) по клику вроде бы происходит логин, но я не могу понять, куда правильно поместить второй код, который получает инфу о пользователе (код с сайта ulogin):

```
$s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$user = json_decode($s, true);
//$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
//$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц. сети
//$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
//$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя
```

Т.е. тут вижу мы парсим что-то, но вот как понять, есть ли оно там и по какому вообще событию проверять и, например, заносить/не заносить в базу, по isset post[token]? Подскажите, если кто знает, что это за событие. Рассматриваю варианты с аяксом и без.

Comment: И где на сайте ulogin.ru такой код?

Comment: http://ulogin.ru/constructor.html

Answer (score 2):

Сорри, не заметил этот код..

Если сайт полностью самописный, то в самое начало index.php (после session_start) вставляем этот код и добавляем две строчки после него..

```
if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
   $s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $_POST['token'] . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
   $user = json_decode($s, true);
   //$user['network'] - соц. сеть, через которую авторизовался пользователь
   //$user['identity'] - уникальная строка определяющая конкретного пользователя соц.  сети
   //$user['first_name'] - имя пользователя
   //$user['last_name'] - фамилия пользователя

   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
   header('Location: /');
}
```

Можно также сделать что угодно с данными: записать в базу или еще что-то..  Но надо не забыть проверить, вернул ли этот сервис правильные данные..  Как это сделать - написано у них в FAQ

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//u-login.com/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,odnoklassniki,mailru,facebook;hidden=other;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F"></div>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.